# How to change one setting in variable

Tags: javascript, variables, leaflet

I have circle markers on a map that use fillColors (total of 8 colors) depending on what value (Ankomsttid) has to show how distance increase from two starting points,  the more further away from starting point the more red the marker will be.

My problem is that I also want to change the circles "outer color ring" or border using property color: (not the fillColor) depending on columns value "Plats" to differentiate and show which starting point (Plats) the marker belongs to. All the markers always use the 8 "spectral fillColors" but need to change the border depending on (Plats) value in this example "S" or "H".

Do I need to write a new set of code or can I just change the "color:" part that is already there in variable? What I need is to change the "color:"-part depending what the properties "Plats" has for value. For example if "Plats" has value = "S" then change to "color: 'blue'" (instead of black) or if "Plats" has value = "H" then change to "color: 'red' (instead of black). This is the code, thanks...

```
 pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var tid = feature.properties.Ankomsttid;
    var pla = feature.properties.Plats;

    var avst;


// base Circkel object
// Since fillColor is the only different value
// predefine all the others
function avstCirkel(fillColor){
    this.fillColor = fillColor
    this.radius = 5
    this.fill = true
    this.color = "#000000"
    this.weight = 1
    this.opacity = 1
    this.fillOpacity = 1
}


// Now you can make all your cirkels easily
// and they can be referenced with avstCirkels[0],
// avstCirkels[1], etc...
let avstCirkels = [
  new avstCirkel('#3288bd'),
  new avstCirkel('#66c2a5'),
  new avstCirkel('#abdda4'),
  new avstCirkel('#e6f598'),
  new avstCirkel('#fee08b'),
  new avstCirkel('#fdae61'),
  new avstCirkel('#f46d43'),
  new avstCirkel('#d53e4f')
]


const colors = {
  S: "blue",
  H: "red"
}
// forEach will loop through all the cirkels and perform a function
avstCirkels.forEach(cirk => cirk.color = colors[pla] || "black")
//console.log("colors: ", avstCirkels[1].color, avstCirkels[2].color)


       // Filter to change the fillColor on circleMarkers
    if (tid > 0 && tid < 201){
        avst = new L.circleMarker(latlng, avstCirkel[0]);
      } 
    else if (tid > 200 && tid < 401){
        avst = new L.circleMarker(latlng, avstCirkel[1]);
      } 
    else if (tid > 400 && tid < 601){
        avst = new L.circleMarker(latlng, avstCirkel[2]);
      }
    else if (tid > 600 && tid < 801){
        avst = new L.circleMarker(latlng, avstCirkel[3]);
      }
    else if (tid > 800 && tid < 1001){
        avst = new L.circleMarker(latlng, avstCirkel[4]);
      }
    else if (tid > 1000 && tid < 1201){
        avst = new L.circleMarker(latlng, avstCirkel[5]);
      }
    else if (tid > 1200 && tid < 1401){
        avst = new L.circleMarker(latlng, avstCirkel[6]);
      }
    else if (tid > 1400){
        avst = new L.circleMarker(latlng, avstCirkel[7]);
      }
        else {
        avst =  null
      }
      return avst;
      }
```

**EDIT** I actually find my error, when referencing to avstCirkel I forgot the "s" should read "avstCirkels[0]" not "avstCirkel[0], now things turns out much better :)

Comment: You can change the property on an object directly , ie: `avstCirkel_8.color = #abab12` Is that what you mean?

Comment: I have to change all 8 colors if the criteria is met so not only for one avstCirkel. If the criteria is not met it will use the default black color. I was thinking if there is a kind of "grouping" the markers and change them at once or if there is a better solution doing this...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this depending on when you need to set the color. If you know the value of `Plats` when defining the circles you can use it in the definition:

```js
// Map Plat value to colors:
let pla = 'S'
const colors = {
  S: "blue",
  H: "red"
}

var avstCirkel_1 = {
 radius: 5,
 fill: true,
 fillColor: '#3288bd',
 color: colors[pla] || '#000000', // will use pla if there is a color mapping otherwise black
 weight: 1,
 opacity: 1,
 fillOpacity: 1
};

console.log("circle color: ", avstCirkel_1.color)
```

If you need to defined them first, then at some point in the future change them all based on some condition, I would suggest changing the structure of your code. In general, if you are creating a bunch a variables with names like `var_1`, `var_2`, `var_3`, that's a good indication you should be using an array. Especially if you want to perform operations on them as a group.

If you make a base `Cirkle` object you can define defaults, and base your objects off of this. Then store them in an array rather than individual variables. This will simplify you code quite a lot:

```js
// base Circkel object
// Since fillColor is the only different value
// predefine all the others
function avstCirkel(fillColor){
    this.fillColor = fillColor
    this.radius = 5
    this.fill = true
    this.color = "#000000"
    this.weight = 1
    this.opacity = 1
    this.fillOpacity = 1
}


// Now you can make all your cirkels easily
// and they can be referenced with avstCirkels[0],
// avstCirkels[1], etc...
let avstCirkels = [
  new avstCirkel('#3288bd'),
  new avstCirkel('#66c2a5'),
  new avstCirkel('#abdda4'),
  new avstCirkel('#e6f598'),
  new avstCirkel('#fee08b'),
  new avstCirkel('#fdae61'),
  new avstCirkel('#f46d43'),
  new avstCirkel('#d53e4f')
]

// now its easy to perform operations on them as a group
// for example, change all colors based on pla:
var pla = 'H'

const colors = {
  S: "blue",
  H: "red"
}
// forEach will loop through all the cirkels and perform a function
avstCirkels.forEach(cirk => cirk.color = colors[pla] || "black")
console.log("colors: ", avstCirkels[1].color, avstCirkels[2].color)
```

Of course you can mix these methods and change which properties are defined as defaults and which are passed as parameters.

Comment: Very detailed answer, many thanks. I see that an array is the way to go, but I do not get it correct, running your suggestion turns all markers to blue default, there is something I do wrong... I did edit the post with the update...

Comment: @QGIS, Abe all markers changed to red because `pla = 'H'`. If `planet = "S"` all colors would be blue, if `pal = undefined` or some other value all colors will be black. I thought you wanted to "change all 8 colors if the criteria is met".

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. I'll try my best and edit the post as now the fill color is blank and the outer ring is all blue, but it should be a mix of blue and red as Plats has more values then only S and fill color should not change